# If $A$ and $B$ are two events such that $P(A)+P(A^{c}|B)=1$, then $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to understand why the following claim is true:

*If $A$ and $B$ are two events such that $P(A)+P(A^{c}|B)=1$, then $A$ and $B$ are independent ($A^{c}$ is the complement of $A$).*

Because I know that $P(A)+P(A^{c})=1$, I think that it must be true that $P(A^{c}|B) = \frac{P(A^{c}\cap B)}{P(B)} = P(A^{c}).$ Then, I can conclude that the events $A^{c}$ and $B$ are independent. Assuming my reasoning is correct, I am not sure how to conclude that the events $A$ and $B$ are also independent.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. The last step is to use the fact that if $A^c$ and $B$ are independent then $A$ and $B$ are also independent. This is because $$P(B) = P(A\cap B) + P(A^c\cap B) = P(A\cap B) + P(A^c)P(B),$$ where we used the fact $A^c$ and $B$ are independent  for the last equality. Rearranging then gives $$P(A\cap B) = \left(1-P(A^c)\right)P(B) = P(A)P(B).$$